# Is it possible to trigger Android app updates programmatically without user interaction using Google Play Core Library?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm currently working on an Android app and exploring the possibility of performing app updates without requiring explicit user interaction. I've looked into the Google Play Core Library for in-app updates, but it seems to involve user prompts for both flexible and immediate update types.

Is there any way to achieve updates silently or without user interaction? My use case involves scenarios where I want to ensure that updates are applied seamlessly in the background without interrupting the user experience.

I'd appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to handle app updates programmatically without explicit user involvement.

Here's a simplified version of my current code:

```
private void checkForAppUpdate() {
    AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

    InstallStateUpdatedListener installStateUpdatedListener = state -> {
        if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
            appUpdateManager.completeUpdate();
            restartApp();
        }
    };
    appUpdateManager.registerListener(installStateUpdatedListener);

    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo = task.getResult();
            if (appUpdateInfo != null && appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
                startUpdateFlow(appUpdateInfo, appUpdateManager);
            }
        } else {
            Exception exception = task.getException();
            if (exception != null) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Failed to get AppUpdateInfo: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

private void startUpdateFlow(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfo, AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager) {
    try {
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                appUpdateInfo,
                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                this,
                MY_UPDATE_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to modify this code or implement a different approach to achieve silent or userless updates?

Comment: on a normal device i don't know, if you were running some sort of point of sales device or something similar it would probably be possible to force updates

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to achieve updates silently or without user interaction?

No, in terms of APKs/AABs.

> My use case involves scenarios where I want to ensure that updates are applied seamlessly in the background without interrupting the user experience.

By definition, that is not possible for APKs/AABs. You cannot update an app without terminating its process, and that will interrupt the user experience.

You could look to move much of your business logic into scripting languages, such as using JavaScript via [zipline](https://github.com/cashapp/zipline), as you could *very carefully* [update those scripts securely](https://github.com/cashapp/zipline/#secure).

Comment: How about this library? https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker

Comment: @DulibaIonut: That library is 12 years old, is undocumented, and has no software license (e.g., Apache 2).